# Automation support for RichTextBox - Unable to get text using White'sUI

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation

I am trying to read the Text from RichTextBox using [White's UI automation framework](http://teststack.azurewebsites.net/white/index.html)  however it always returns null.

Already added the below code to the RichtextBox.cs

```
   protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
    {
        return new RichTextBoxAutomationPeer(this);
    }
```

Is there any workaround to get the text? or by using TextPattern?

Answer (score 2):

I have been using white for a while now, I know this is really late , but i had the same issue. I have used text pattern to get the value from a rich text box, find the sample code below , hope this helps in anyway.

```
 AutomationElement ele =window.GetElement(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("richTextBoxId>"));

        if (ele != null)
        {
            TextPattern txtPattern = ele.GetCurrentPattern(TextPattern.Pattern) as TextPattern;
            String controlText = txtPattern.DocumentRange.GetText(-1);
            Debug.WriteLine("the text is" + controlText);

        }
```